# Issue with joining a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get students who havent attending any of the particular seminars. However, this is not working.

```
SELECT Student.FirstName,Student.LastName 
from Student WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1 from Seminar A
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Individual B
                        ON A.SeminarID=B.IndividualID AND    B.LastName='Johns'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Group C
                        ON A.SeminarID=C.GroupID AND   C.GroupName='Koir Media Pvt Ltd'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderProcessor G 
                        ON F.OrderID=G.OrderID
                        INNER JOIN EventSeminar D
                        ON D.SeminarID=A.SeminarID
                        INNER JOIN AudiEvent E
                        ON D.EventID=E.EventID
                        INNER JOIN Reserver  F
                        ON E.EventID=F.EventID
                        INNER JOIN Student H
                        ON G.StudentID=H.StudentID
                        where G.StudentID=H.StudentID);
```

Output -

```
FirstName   LastName
  Matt       Johnson
 Mattew      John
  Shane      Watson
```

Input -

Student

```
StudentID   FirstName   LastName
1           Matt        Johnson
2           Mattew      John
3           Shane       Watson
4           Bill        Nielsen
5           Garry       Stevenson
```

OrderProcessor

```
OrderID StudentID
O01         1
O02         2
O03         3
O04         4
O05         5
O06         4
O07         3
O08         2
O09         1
O10         5
O11         2
O12         3
O13         1
O14         4
O15         1
O16         1
```

Reserver

```
ReserverID  OrderID AudiID  EventID
R01           O01     1       E01
R02           O02     1       E01
R03           O03     1       E01
R04           O04     1       E02
R05           O05     1       E02
R06           O06     1       E02
R07           O07     1       E02
R08           O08     1       E03
R09           O09     2       E03
R10           O10     2       E03
R11           O11     2       E03
R12           O12     2       E04
R13           O13     2       E04
R14           O14     2       E04
R15           O15     2       E05
R16           O16     2       E05
```

AudiEvent

```
EventID AudiID  
  E01     1 
  E02     1 
  E03     2 
  E04     2 
  E05     2
```

EventSeminar

```
EventID SeminarID   
  E01     S01   
  E02     S02   
  E03     S03   
  E04     S04   
  E05     S05   
  E01     S06   
  E02     S07   
  E03     S08   
  E04     S09   
  E05     S10
```

Seminar

```
SeminarID   IndividualID    GroupID
   S01        I01            null
   S02        I02            null
   S03        I03            null
   S04        I04            null
   S05        I05            null
   S06        null           G01
   S07        null           G02
   S08        null           G03
   S09        null           G04
   S10        null           G05
```

Individual

```
IndividualID    FirstName   LastName
    I01          Steven      Johns
    I02          Barkha      Dutt
    I03          Pronoy      Roy
    I04          Alan        Wilkins
    I05          Harsha      Bhogle
```

Group

```
GroupID GroupName   
  G01   Koir Media Pvt Ltd  
  G02   Headlines Today 
  G03   The Age 
  G04   TOI 
  G05   HT
```

Could you please help me what is the issue with my query? My query does not give me the right result...

Comment: You know `group` is a reserved word, right?

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes. However, here it is being used in table.

Comment: can u post the tables and some data in the http://sqlfiddle.com and expected output in the question ?

Comment: Well I guess that's OK then !?!?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry- Is the query ok?

Comment: The more I see this schema, the more problems I have with it.  Are you allowed to make any changes?  And what should the _correct_ results be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Try this:

"Students who havent attending any of the particular seminars"

```
Select s.FirstName, s.LastName, StudentSeminars.SeminarCount
From Student s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT o.StudentID, count(r.EventID) as SeminarCount
           FROM OrderProcessor o
           INNER JOIN Reserver r on r.OrderID = o.OrderID
           INNER JOIN EventSeminar e on e.EventID = t.EventID
           INNER JOIN Seminar s on s.SeminarID = e.SeminarID
           LEFT JOIN Individual i on i.IndividualID = s.IndividualID
           LEFT JOIN Group g on g.GroupID = s.GroupID
           WHERE i.LastName='Johns' OR g.GroupName='Koir Media Pvt Ltd'
           GROUP BY o.StudentID ) StudentSeminars
    ON StudentSeminars.StudentId = s.StudentId
WHERE StudentSeminars.SeminarCount IS NULL
```

The sub-select gets a list of all students who reserved a place on a seminar with a count of how many seminars. The main query then starts with a list of all students and joins onto the sub-select to find out which of those students haven't attended any seminars!

I have assumed that the presence of a record in the Reserver table means a student has "attended a particular seminar". I have also assumed that not all events are seminars hence the join to the EventSeminar table to ensure we are only counting seminars.

Comment: -I intend to find students who havn't attended a particular seminar. U putin the individual or group name in my query, and it will tell you which student did not attend that seminar. Your query is going in for students who haven't attended seminar at all in the first place...

Comment: @MrCoder I've updated the query to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks Sarin, this one is working fine. I think my query is also somewhat correct as am getting one of the results, when I compare with the output of your query. Could you please review it and let me know where am going wrong?

Comment: At the point you are LEFT joining tables which are LEFT joined to each other, it all starts to get confused. A LEFT join will produce NULLs where the join doesn't match. If you then join on top of those nulls it can then lead to unexpected consequences. I'm presuming much like the ones you have experienced. My best guess anyhow.

Comment: Yes, am getting what you mean. I have made the change in my query, pls suggest if this is fine?

Comment: @MrCoder your Stident table is inner joined to your OrderProcessor table which is left joined. this may also produce odd results. Best you reorder your query so all inner joins are done first and then left joins.

Comment: Could you pls chk now?

Comment: Same problem! I have to go now!

Comment: No worries! let me know once u have time pls.